# How to inspect default export function from Jest manual mock

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, fetch

The following manual mock file of `isomorphic-fetch` for Jest tests returns the expected values:

```js
// __mocks__/isomorphic-fetch.ts

import * as req from "./requestData";

const Fetch = (url: string, options: any): Promise<any> => {
  const resultPromise = {
    text: () => {
      return Promise.resolve(req.generateMockResponseData(url, options.body));
    },
  };
  return Promise.resolve(resultPromise);
};

export default Fetch;
```

However I've ran into problems when trying to inspect the arguments with which it was called, as the `mock` property on `fetch` was undefined. I've tried two things:

First, I've wrapped the `Fetch` function in `jest.fn` like this:

```js
const Fetch = jest.fn((url: string, options: any): Promise<any> => {
// implementation is same as above
});

export default Fetch;
```

Now after adding

```js
import _fetchMock  from "isomorphic-fetch"
const fetchMock = _fetchMock as jest.Mock<Promise<any>>;
```

in the test file, I can inspect calls to fetch with

```js
fetchMock.mock.calls[0]
```

But now `fetch` in the application code returns undefined during tests for some reason.

The second thing I've tried was removing the `jest.fn` wrapper from `Fetch` and adding

```js
jest.mock("isomorphic-fetch")
```

to the test file. Now `fetch` returns the expected values in the application code during tests, but `fetchMock.mock` is now undefined again.

Jest config:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  "clearMocks": true,
  "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
  "resetMocks": true,
  "restoreMocks": true,
  "rootDir": "./src",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["Error.ts"],
  "testEnvironmentOptions": {
    "resources": "usable",
    "features": {
      "FetchExternalResources": ["script", "iframe"],
      "ProcessExternalResources": ["script", "iframe"],
    }
  }
}
```

There is a complete example on [GitHub.](https://github.com/dokklib/client-js/blob/56fd505586174847306cae0e6c034eb45dcc1169/src/transports/HTTPTransport.test.ts)

Comment: Please, update the question with spy implementation instead of `// ...` and Jest config. The question should be fully intelligible without navigating to external resources that may become unavailable any time.

Comment: @EstusFlask I've added the Jest config and clarified that the omitted code is the same as in the above snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Jest spy and regular mocked function may behave differently with the same implementation is that Jest spy can be reset to be a no-op.

This exactly what happens in this Jest setup:

```
...
"resetMocks": true,
"restoreMocks": true,
...
```

`restoreMocks` option is generally desirable, it prevents test cross-contamination by resetting spied methods to original implementations.

`resetMocks` is generally undesirable and virtually unusable, it resets reusable spies from `__mocks__` to no-op implementation.

TL;DR: `resetMocks` configuration option and `jest.resetAllMocks()` destroy the implementations of reusable spies and should be generally avoided. If a specific spy needs to be reset, this can be done on a per-case basis with `mockReset` method.

Comment: Thanks, after setting `resetMocks: false` in `jest.config.js` the mock arguments can be inspected as expected.